# Hosting images on Google Code

Tags: hosting, project, wiki, screenshot, google-code

I want to put several screenshots of a project I'm working on, in the wiki and project pages for the project on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/pydlnadms/). How do I host or attach the image files? If this isn't possible, where should I put them?

### Update0

This question has spawned another: [Get certificate fingerprint of HTTPS server from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164804/get-certificate-fingerprint-of-https-server-from-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can put these files in the same repository that holds the wiki - i.e. http://code.google.com/p/pydlnadms/source/checkout?repo=wiki.

These files will be served under http://wiki.pydlnadms.googlecode.com/hg/.